# I can't figure out why Workbox doesn't retrieve from cache when network is down for one route, but works for all others?

Tags: workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

Im using workbox-webpack-plugin and I've successfully set up my service worker as it caches images, css, js and most of my api responses in different caches on an angular front end and python back end

There is one route that never retrieves the api response properly from cache. I keep getting the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) no-response: The strategy could not generate a response for 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/challenges/?is_exclusive=false&is_published=true&consolidate_groups_with_location=true&groups=9413,9404,9413&location_scope=-1&location_continent_id=5&location_country_id=235&location_state_province_id=44&location_region_id=194&location_city_id=14009&ends_at=2019-06-07%2020:54:38'. The underlying error is TypeError: Failed to fetch.
at StaleWhileRevalidate.makeRequest (https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-cdn/releases/4.3.1/workbox-strategies.dev.js:1005:15)
```

The api response for that page is stored in cache storage and has the information necessary to render the info. All my other pages work and I cant figure out why. I'm also at a loss for words on what I need to do to handle this error.

I've tried using this code but the event listener doesnt seem to fire.

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
event.respondWith(
  caches.match(event.request)
    .then(function(response) {
      if (response) {
        return response;     // if valid response is found in cache return it
      } else {
        return fetch(event.request)     //fetch from internet
          .then(function(res) {
            return caches.open("api-local-cache")
              .then(function(cache) {
                cache.put(event.request.url, res.clone());    //save the response for future
                return res;   // return the fetched data
              })
          })
          .catch(function(err) {       // fallback mechanism
            return caches.open('api-local-cache')
              .then(function(cache) {
                return cache.match('/users/me');
              });
          });
      }
    })
);
```

});

this is my workbox strategy

```
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
     new RegExp('http://127.0.0.1:8080'),
     new workbox.strategies.StaleWhileRevalidate({
      cacheName: "api-local-cache"
    })
  );
```

I expect to see my service worker retrieve the stored api response but it doesnt and says failed to fetch.

Comment: Lately been experiencing similar issue but with Nuxt/Vue application